# How to expand luminosity blending option in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, blending

i have an issue with the vector shape in the background in an illustrator file, it appears differently on my client's pc.

That's how it appears to me (the good one):

[image: good]

and that's how it appears to the client:

[image: bad]

The vector shape in the background has transparency 50% and luminosity blending over the orange gradient color.

My question is there any way to expand the luminosity blending option so the vector shape appear the same?

Comment: Have you tried Selecting All and using `Object > Flatten Transparency`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
yes, i tried but it ruined the image

Comment: Define "ruined". It will flattent hings makign editing more difficult, but you can flatten transparency, then save as PDF and revert to a version before the flattening.

Comment: This question is basically the same issue: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21495/weird-grey-boxes-on-pdf-export-and-huge-quality-difference-in-apple-preview-an -- Apple's Preview application is not a great option for complex PDFs.